# Adding confirmation inside validation of editable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I am using editable for my datepicker. I am trying to have some confirmation in my validation but it does not work. Is there something wrong? Here is my code:

```
$('inputdate').editable({
    type: 'date',
    params: function(params){
        params.dateVal = dateVal;
        return params;
    },
     validate : function(value){

        var message = null;
        confirm("Are you sure you sure?",  
         function(result) {             

           if(result){
           //ajax call here
           }
           });
        });
        return message;
        }
        else return 'Notif';
    },
    url: url2,
    success: function(response){
        location.reload();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Do You get any error?

Comment: i don't get any error but  it doesn't get the value of the confirmation (if yes or no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of method **confirm** is wrong, you can read about that method [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

You can used code like this:

```
if (confirm('question')){
 console.log('yes')
}
else{
 console.log('no')
}
```

**EDIT** Using bootbox use this code

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
 Example.show("Confirm result: "+result);
});
```

Comment: it works! but when i use bootbox.confirm it does not work, maybe there's a conflict?

Comment: What is it `bootbox.confirm`?

Comment: You can see it here  (http://bootboxjs.com/) i use this because it let me customize its style

Comment: This library have confirm dialog and You must use it just like in documentation is wrote for this library

Comment: i know. but my problem is when i use bootbox.confirm it doesn't work

Comment: Create you example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and share it, then we can find solution

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak can you help me with bootbox ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344594/x-editable-with-confirmation-prompt-using-bootbox-js