# X-editable with confirmation prompt using bootbox.js

Tags: jquery, x-editable, bootbox

I'm trying to add a confirm prompt into x-editable plugin. If I add using a normal javascript, it works. However, if I try to implement bootbox plugin, it fails. Below is an example of using a normal javascript that works.

```
if(!confirm("Are you sure you wish to proceed?")){
            $('#name2').editable('toggle');
            return "invalid";
        }
```

But if I add bootbox plugin like the example below, it fails to work. It actually change the value before the confirmation.

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel?", function(result) {
            if(result == 'false'){
                return "invalid";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        });
```

Here's the jsfiddle for bigger picture. https://jsfiddle.net/f8vjmqtq/11/

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate your described behavior in the fiddle. If I change the value in the bootbox field/don't it gives me the correct bootbox popup (after clicking).

Comment: it give you the correct popup, but if u click on cancel, the value shoudn;t be changed... You should test out the test 1 and test 2 also.

Comment: bootbox *cannot* block the flow of execution. So, what you're trying to do probably won't work, since the validate function is allowed to complete before the user interacts with the modal.